# PHP/MySQL Order by column in a different table

Tags: php, mysql

I am running this SQL Code:

```
sql=" SELECT * FROM channel_did ";
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$pbx01_conn) or die(mysql_error());
        $counter=0;
        $display='';
        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
        {
            $sql2="SELECT * from client where id = '".$result["client_id"]."' ";
            $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$pbx01_conn) or die(mysql_error());
            $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
}
```

so in the `channel_did` table the `client_id` column is a number then i do a lookup in the `client` table where the id equals the `channel_id.client_id`

how can i get the list (from `channel_did)` to order by the `company` column in the `client` table?

```
**channel_id**
id
did
client_id

**client**
id
name
company

so client.id = channel_did.client_id
```

Comment: what do your channel_did and client tables look like ?

Comment: look at Pascamel's answer and the update that I suggested to it and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write a query with an `inner join` with both tables, select the fields from the first table, and use a column of the second table to sort your rows

```
SELECT a.* FROM channel_did a
INNER JOIN client b on a.client_id = b.id
ORDER BY b.company
```

Of course this is in the case you have one and only one row in `client` corresponding for each row of `channel_did`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this..

```
 SELECT i.* FROM `channel_did` AS i
    JOIN `client` AS c
    ON (i.client_id = c.id)
ORDER BY c.company DESC
```

Comment: table c does not have a client_id field.

Comment: @Maximus2012 was just giving you an example of a JOIN. anyway fixed it